# Why is the background color of my footer not filling my entire footer?

Tags: css, footer

My footer works fine untill I test the responsiveness of my website. When I make the website smaller, the footer becomes 2 lines and goes out of the background color of the footer. How can I fix this? Should I add a Media Query?

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.pageContentWrapper {
padding-bottom: 50px; /* Height of footer*/
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 50px;
background-color: lightgray;
text-align: center;
color: black;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Verdana, serif;
}
```

Comment: it's work fine for me, I can't reproduce this bug. Could you give us a complete html code ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the background color of the page the footer color and set the background color for the content to be white.

```css
body,html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.main-content{
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum
</div>

<div class="footer">FOOTER CONTENT HERE</div>
```